# Two Sum, Pass value from inside to function call?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I tried to pass unique pairs which sum meet the target to the function call. Kind of new with python so let me know how I can fix it.

```
array = [ 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, -1, 6 ]
target = 9
def twoSum (array, target):
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        for x in range( i + 1, len(array)):
            totalOfTwo = array[i] + array[x]
            if (totalOfTwo == target):
                pairsList = (array[i], array[x])
    return -1
result = twoSum (array, target)

if result != -1:
    print ("the intergers numbers meet target", result)
else:
    print ("result is not in range")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Some more details about your question would be extremely helpful. What is the issue you are having with your code? A good question should have a minimal reproducible example, the output you are getting, and the output you are expecting.

Comment: Looks like you're you're trying to find two elements in `array` which sum to `target`, with early termination (only returns the first such pair found). One style tip for legibility: since you call your first index `i`, call the second one `k`, not `x`, which makes it unclear whether x is a value or index. Also, Python calls lists lists, not 'arrays', unlike Java.

Comment: Second tip: it's more Pythonic to `return None` than return a sentinel value like -1. The caller can then test the return the value with simply `if result:`, you don't need any `if result != -1` or `if result is None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You forgot to return the result

You'r code

```py
array = [ 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, -1, 6 ]
target = 9
def twoSum (array, target):
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        for x in range( i + 1, len(array)):
            totalOfTwo = array[i] + array[x]
            if (totalOfTwo == target):
                pairsList = (array[i], array[x]) ##### THIS #####
    return -1
result = twoSum (array, target)

if result != -1:
    print ("the intergers numbers meet target", result)
else:
    print ("result is not in range")
```

My code

```py
array = [ 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, -1, 6 ]
target = 9
def twoSum (array, target):
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        for x in range( i + 1, len(array)):
            totalOfTwo = array[i] + array[x]
            if (totalOfTwo == target):
               return (array[i], array[x]) ##### THIS ####
    return -1
result = twoSum (array, target)

if result != -1:
    print ("the intergers numbers meet target", result)
else:
    print ("result is not in range")
```

But this is only the first result, so...

```py
array = [ 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, -1, 6 ]
target = 9
def twoSum (array, target):
    rsts = [] # save rsts hear
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        for x in range( i + 1, len(array)):
            totalOfTwo = array[i] + array[x]
            if (totalOfTwo == target):
               rsts.append((array[i], array[x])) # add answer to rsts
    return -rsts
result = twoSum (array, target)
```

if we haven't correct answer result is an empty list (`[]`), so

```py
if result != []: # changed -1 with []
    print ("the intergers numbers meet target", result)
else:
    print ("result is not in range")
```

Comment: Good answer as it helps OP identify the problem, but I personally assumed the goal was to create a list of all the tuple combinations rather than return the first one.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and only return the first unique pair. Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for?

You need to add the pairs to the list, and return them if any are found.

Also, personally I would return the empty list rather than -1 if none are found, as they are different data types.

```
array = [ 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, -1, 6 ]
target = 9
def twoSum (array, target):
    pairsList = []
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        for x in range( i + 1, len(array)):
            totalOfTwo = array[i] + array[x]
            if (totalOfTwo == target):
                pairsList.append((array[i], array[x]))
    if len(pairsList) == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return pairsList
result = twoSum (array, target)

if result != -1:
    print ("the intergers numbers meet target", result)
else:
    print ("result is not in range")
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The most Pythonic way to implement this is as a list-comprehension, it's just a one-liner!

```
>>> [(a[i],a[j]) for i in range(0, len(a)-1) for j in range(i+1, len(a)-1) if a[i]+a[j]==target]

[(4, 5), (10, -1)]
```

(Note that lend itself to doing early termination, but you can just slice [0]'th element.)

As to your code/ functional approach, I'd rewrite it as this (next time please ask for reviews of working code over on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), rather than here on SO):

```
def two_sum (a, target):
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        for j in range( i + 1, len(a)):
            if a[i] + a[j] == target:
                return (a[i], a[j])
    return None

result = two_sum (a, target)

if result:
    print ("the numbers sum to target", result)
else:
    print ("result is not in range")
```

Comments:

- since you call your first index i, **call the second index j**, not x, which makes it unclear whether x is a value or index
- it's far **more Pythonic to return None** than return a sentinel value like -1. The caller can then just test the return the value with simply `if result:`, you don't need any clunky `if result != -1` or `if result is None`
- renamed `twoSum` to **`two_sum`** to follow Python naming convention (PEP-8) for function names and variables: lower_case_with_underscores
- note this implementation does early termination. But if you just change `return (a[i], a[j])` to `yield (a[i], a[j])`, that makes it a generator that sequentially returns all(/any) matching tuples. (you'd need to replace the `return None` with `yield StopIteration`)
- similarly `totalOfTwo` would be called `total_of_two` or `pair_sum`
- but there's no need to declare temporary variables for `totalOfTwo`,`pairsList`, just use the expressions directly
- recommend you learn the right Python terminology, if you're coming from Java. `pairsList` is not a list, it's a tuple. `array` is not an array, it's a list. But I'd just call it `a`.
- note we only need to run the left index `i` up to len(a)-1 instead of len(a), since we know we'll need j to index an element on its right.